# How can I theme a form "checkboxes" element?

Tags: theming, forms

I've got a checkboxes field displayed on the user profile form. I'm trying to restyle that field to put the description BEFORE the checkboxes. That seems like it should be a simple thing?

So far I've got:

```
function MYTHEME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['my_field_id'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#theme'] = 'checkboxes_description_before_element';
}

function MYTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'checkboxes_description_before_element' => array(
            'render element' => 'element',
            'function' => 'theme_checkboxes_description_before_element'
        ),
    );
}

function MYTHEME_checkboxes_description_before_element($variables) {
    return "XYZ";
}
```

The checkboxes field is still stubbornly sitting on the markup generated by [theme_checkboxes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_checkboxes/7) instead of "XYZ".

I know that the form element is getting the new '#theme' through checking with `dpm()`.

Comment: You can use form #prefix attribute..

Comment: Hi @AnilSagar - #prefix would add the markup before the title right? That's not what I want. I'd really prefer full control over the markup for the form element in question.

Comment: Hi @George - can you post the actual markup and intended markup in your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkboxes description is not rendered in `theme_checkboxes` or `theme_checkbox`. It comes from `theme_form_element`.

1. If you want every form element on the site (not just checkboxes) to have the description first, then you could just override and modify `theme_form_element`.
2. If you want only specific checkboxes to have this, then you could override and modify `theme_form_element` to position the description based on a variable (similar to what it already does with `#title_display`). You could then set the variable when creating the FAPI array.
3. If you want all checkboxes (but only checkboxes) to follow this behaviour, then you could override `theme_form_element` as above, and use `hook_element_info_alter()` and change `checkboxes` to have the new variable you created appopriately set.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do you override and modify theme_form_element - is this a hook? So can it be overridden like other hooks?

Comment: @therobyouknow it's just a theme function, so eg. provide MYTHEME_form_element() or form_element.tpl.php.

Comment: +1 upvote on comment and answer thankyou @Andy! Following on from your confirmation, I looked into it further and the definition is at: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7.x (I don't know why I missed it in the first place. But much obliged!)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be pretty similar to [How to theme a radio button field on node edit form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/30330/11950), I think this should explain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before and I can find the code if this first suggestion doesn't work.

If you just need to put the description before the checkboxes, you can use `hook_form_alter` and add a [`#field_prefix`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_prefix) to the field.

I assume you have the knowledge to extract the field description, unset it from below the checkboxes and put it into the `#field_prefix`?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 functions that are responsible to theme checkboxes: [`theme_checkboxes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_checkboxes/7) and [`theme_checkbox()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_checkbox/7). Where the former themes the wrapper div around the checkboxes, the latter themes the individual checkboxes.

If you want to override one of them or both you should copy them in `template.php` file under your theme folder and rename like `YOURTHEME_checkboxes` and `YOURTHEME_checkbox`.

Then don't forget to clear the caches.